# Codeigniter display records from table 2 for each record with id similar to table 1

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been bugged by this problem in CodeIgniter. I want to display all records in table 2 for each record in table 1. like this illustration:

```
id | name |             id | pets |
1  | john doe |          1 | dogs |
2  | jane doe |          1 | cats |
                         2 | hamsters |
                         2 | birds |
                         2 | iguanas |
```

and display like this in views:

```
id: 1
name: John doe
pets: dogs, cats

id: 2
name: jane doe
pets: hamsters, birds, iguanas
```

this is an analogy. any way to do it?

Comment: please provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What have you tried so far?  StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with a [mcve]. For more information, please see [ask].

Comment: there is a relationship between both tables??

Comment: **1st:** your second table should have a unique id column, with id 1,2,3, etc. **2nd:** change current id of 2nd table into owner_id for example. **3rd:** read about joins [Mysql join clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) and [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Answer (score 0):

Since your problem is not clear because you are not given any code. I have give only idea to join the tables. You can write query like this in codeigniter.

```
$data = $this->db->query("SELECT a1.id,al.name,a2.pets FROM TableA a1
INNER JOIN TableB a2 
ON a1.id = a2.id WHERE a1.id=1")->result(); // here you got objects

print_r($data); //This will show the result
```

If you give your code then we will surely solve your problem.